# GridSearchCV error: Expected array-like (array or non-string sequence), got

Tags: python, scikit-learn, h2o

I am currently modelling using H20, nonetheless i am working with Scikit learn pipelines.

1. First i created the baseline model with the following code:

```
clf_pipe = Pipeline(
        steps = [("impute missing", replace_missing_vars),
                 ("scale", scale),
                 ("dim_reduction", pca),
                 ("classifier", gbm)])

clf = clf_pipe.fit(train[x], train[y])
r2 = clf[len(clf)-1].r2(test[x], test[y])
```

2. Now i want to hypertune the model by running a gridsearch as follows:

```
parameters = {'ntree': [24, 50, 100], 'max_depth': [5,10], 'learn_rate':[0.25, 0.5, 0.65]}

gs_clf = GridSearchCV(clf_pipe, param_grid=params)
clf = gs_clf.fit(train[x], train[y])
```

3. But i get the following explicit error message (It is not incomplete, it ends like that):

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/multiclass.py in type_of_target(y)
    239     if not valid:
    240         raise ValueError('Expected array-like (array or non-string sequence), '
--> 241                          'got %r' % y)
    242 
    243     sparse_pandas = (y.__class__.__name__ in ['SparseSeries', 'SparseArray'])

ValueError: Expected array-like (array or non-string sequence), got
```

If you wonder how does the train data looks like, this is the dataframe structure:

```
trin[x] = {'nartd_share': 'real',
 'nanrtd_share': 'real',
 'hot_beverages_share': 'real',
 'alcoholic_beverages_share': 'real',
 'all_beverages_share': 'int',
 'pfand_share': 'int',
 'if_top7_cities': 'enum',
 'opening_days': 'real',
 'opening_hours': 'real',
 'closing_hours': 'real',
 'open_at_b_of': 'real',
 'close_at_e_of': 'real',
 'busiest_at': 'real',
 'most_revenue_at': 'real',
 'opening_at_cosine': 'real',
 'closing_at_cosine': 'real',
 'busiest_at_cosine': 'real',
 'most_revenue_at_cosine': 'real',
 'weekend_opening_hours': 'real',
 'weekday_opening_hours': 'real',
 'avg_overnight_hours': 'real',
 'if_overnight': 'enum',
 'if_sunday': 'enum',
 'monthly_revenue': 'real',
 'monthly_quantity': 'real',
 'monthly_alcohol_revenue': 'real',
 'monthly_7vat_share': 'real',
 'weekly_revenue': 'real',
 'weekly_quantity': 'real',
 'weekly_alcohol_revenue': 'real',
 'weekly_7vat_share': 'real',
 'daily_revenue': 'real',
 'daily_quantity': 'real',
 'daily_alcohol_revenue': 'real',
 'daily_7vat_share': 'real',
 'avg_alcohol_price': 'real',
 'avg_nartd_price': 'real',
 'max_alcohol_price': 'real',
 'max_nartd_price': 'real',
 'top1_product': 'enum',
 'top2_product': 'enum',
 'top3_product': 'enum'}

train[y] = {'segment': 'enum'}
```

Comment: got *what*? there must be something there (in the error message)... And what are `x` and `y`?

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, change params to parameters; the argument passed earlier.

```py
gs_clf = GridSearchCV(clf_pipe, param_grid=params)
```

Then becomes:

```py
gs_clf = GridSearchCV(clf_pipe, param_grid=parameters)
```